# How to convert a Dynamics Advanced Find query to LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

**Overview:**

I've coded a simple console app that can connect to a Dynamics CRM instance following on from this [walk-through](https://arunpotti.wordpress.com/2014/12/09/connect-to-crm-online-or-on-premise-using-c/).

Now I need to create a second method that will perform a filtered query on the users of that CRM within the C# code using LINQ.

**Advanced Find Queries:**

I tried this out using the [Advanced Find search](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm-customer-center/create-edit-or-save-an-advanced-find-search.aspx) on Dynamics which equates to the following:

```
Query 1:

Look for: Users
Primary Email Status -> Equals -> Pending Approval

Query 2:

Look for: Users
Select -> Mailbox 
Status -> Equals -> Inactive
```

**Question:**

How can the two queries above be translated to LINQ within the [Dynamics SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/download/details.aspx?id=44567) C# code?

Comment: If you have created an Advanced Find you can download the Fetch XML from CRM and use that to create a `FetchExpression`.

Comment: @Nicknow I'm going to take this approach. You can post that suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328028.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article?

The actual LINQ queries will look something like this:

```
 var users = from systemUser in crmServiceContext.SystemUserSet  
             where systemUser.PrimaryEmailStatus == //some value 
             select systemUser;
```

Comment: I used a FetchXML for this case as I can export from the advanced find in CRM. Any idea on casting the query result to a string? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35280788/how-to-convert-an-entitycollection-to-list

Answer (score 2):

You can use pretty much standard LINQ there as Gilgamesh answered.

Be careful because the CRM linq provider only implements a subset of LINQ features ans some operations aren't allowed like:

- GroupBy
- More than 1 left outer joins
- Order by a related column
- ...

There are many complex examples of the queries you can use [here](https://github.com/jordimontana82/fake-xrm-easy/blob/master/FakeXrmEasy.Tests/FakeContextTests/LinqTests/FakeContextTestLinqQueries.cs)

Answer (score 0):

If you use [LinQPad](http://www.linqpad.net) with the [Dynamics CRM Driver](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crminthefield/2015/04/24/linqpad-4-driver-for-dynamics-crm-is-available-on-codeplex/) you can obtain the resulting FetchXml of a Linq query. Other thing you can do is execute your fetchxml string directly in crm without changing it to a linq or lambda [(example here)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328117.aspx)

hope it helps